# Error while using decompose and stl functions in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am new to time series analysis and I am trying out some codes seen in some tutorials. I am using stock prices as the time series data.

```
library(quantmod)
aapl=getSymbols("AAPL",from="2015-01-01",auto.assign=F)
is.ts(aapl)
ts.aapl=as.ts(aapl)
is.ts(ts.aapl)
x=Cl(ts.aapl)
head(x)
plot(decompose(s))
plot(stl(x))
```

But its showing these errors

```
> plot(decompose(x))
Error in decompose(x) : time series has no or less than 2 periods
> plot(stl(x))
Error in stl(x) : series is not periodic or has less than two periods
```

is the error is due to its lack of seasonality and trend?

Answer (score 1):

The error is likely due to the fact that your `x` is an irregular time series: there are temporal gaps, e.g. no data on 2015-01-03, 2015-01-04. You will have to implement your own version of `decompose`, e.g. following this approach:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623027/how-to-analyse-irregular-time-series-in-r